# A fixed position child inside a relative parent renders not related to the parent in Chrome

Tags: css, css-position

Let's say I have an element on my website with a position relative. And inside that element I want an other element with position fixed.

**The Problem:**

In all browsers (FF, IE, Opera) and in earlier Chrome browsers ( tested on Chrome version 26.0.1410) the fixed element is positioned related to the relative position of the parent. In the current Chrome browser (tested on Chrome version 32.0.1700) this fixed child is rendered to the the parent without taking its parents relative position in account.

```css
#parent-element {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 90%;
}

#child-element {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-element">
  <div id="child-element"></div>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle, the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9q3v6/1/)

Comment: _“In all browsers (FF, IE, Opera) and in earlier chrome browsers ( tested on Chrome version 26.0.1410 ) the fixed element is positioned related to the relative position of the parent.”_ – that would mean that _all_ those browsers would be doing it _wrong_, because per specification the containing block for a fixed positioned element is _always_ the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you want the "absolute" position value instead of the "fixed" value, not sure why/when a change would have happened but according to w3c - Fixed: The element is positioned relative to the browser window. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

http://jsfiddle.net/9q3v6/3/

```
 #parent-element{
     border: 1px solid red;
     height: 100px;
     position: relative;
     top: 50px;
     width: 90%;
 }
 #child-element{
     background-color: yellow;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Apparantly the fixed element inherits it's start position from it's parent. From there it indeed is positioned relative to the browser window. This was usualy the case en I often used it this way to position the fixed element.

Thanx for your hint. To position the fixed element proparly i then should just put it directly inside the body element.